# Watson conversation gives correct intent but not the expected response from that intent

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

I'm using Watson Conversation as an FAQ, ie each question that the user asks is expected to NOT relate to the previous one. 
Expected example:

```
User: How to book a meeting room? 
Watson: Go to this website, click here, press that....

User: When will I know the results of my application?
Watson: You will receive notice within two weeks if your application is successful.

User: How to upgrade my laptop?
Watson: Log a ticket at this website...
```

My dialog nodes look like the following, without any child nodes.

```
welcome
#bookroom
#upgradehardware
#applicationresults
anything_else
```

But now I am getting the correct intent with high confidence, but the output is always a response from the anything_else node.

```
User: How to book a meeting room? 
[Intent: #bookroom]
Watson: Sorry I don't understand

User: When will I know the results of my application?
[Intent: #applicationresults]
Watson: Can you please rephrase?

User: How to upgrade my laptop?
[Intent: #upgradehardware]
Watson: I didn't get your meaning.
```

Help? How am I supposed to treat each node independently?

Comment: Do the conditions for the dialog nodes match the intent? How is the flow?

Comment: @data_henrik the condition is exactly the intent. The nodes are like this: if bot recognizes intent, then respond with... , and finally wait for user input, for all of them.

Comment: Add `<? intents ?>` to the `anything_else` node, and show the results. It is likely it is getting the right intent, but it is below 20% confidence.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty what is "<? intents ?>"? from the json returned by api, the confidence for the correct intent is between 0.8 to 1

Comment: That command will show you the full intents+confidences, even if you are not using `alternate_intents`. If you confidence level is high, then second thing to check is if you stored the intent as "condition" and not an intent. But they fixed that sometime back, so I doubt it is that.  One other option is to do a full refresh of your workspace (restart browser). I've seen cases where `anything_else` got moved, but the UI didn't reflect it. 

If none of that works, without a reproducible scenario posted not sure how someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Add user Examples** in IBM Watson Assistant. Give your custom inputs there (*What your customers suppose to ask Training your conversation service* ).
[image]

This may solve your problem.